# Is there something like variadic functions in Centura?

Tags: variadic-functions, guptateamdeveloper, centura

Is it possible to have optional parameters in Centura 6.1?

Like:

```
test( boolean , hWnd... )
```

And how would I declare them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gupta TeamDeveloper v6.3 onwards supports Overloaded Constructors , allowing you to declare any number of Constructors with different parameter types. The compiler decides which constructor to use according to the parameter list you send it. See below for a simple example of calling the Constructor using 1) a Boolean parameter and then 2) a String Parameter.

[image: TeamDeveloper supports Overloaded Constructors]

Comment: ps You can do the same with Functions.  i.e. Overload them .

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Team Developer does not support optional parameters.

Comment: Overload functions are supported from v7 onwards.